# How to let a for loop set the variable of preg_match($patternArray[$i], $inp, $matches.$i )?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop, preg-match

I want to use preg_match and loop it and the output should be six $matches1 - $matches6

The code below leads to:
Only variables can be passed by reference Error

```
$patternArray = array($pK, $pGd, $pA, $pB, $pF, $pGF, $pAbo, $pGFK, $pGGK);

for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    preg_match($patternArray[$i], $input, $ucmatches . $i);
};
```

I already tried

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
$m = ${'matches'.$i};
preg_match($patternArray[$i], $input, $m);

};
```

results in

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches1 in new.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches2 in new.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches3 in new.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches4 in new.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches5 in new.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: matches in new.php on line 26
NULL
```

Comment: Try adding matches to an array instead of a concatenated variable: `$ucmatches[$i]`

Comment: the problem with that is $ucmatches1 as wished is an array of 46 keys and with set tho $ucmatches[1] its splits wierdly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably trying to do something like this:

```
$ucmatches = array(); // not necessary but good practice
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    preg_match($patternArray[$i], $input, $ucmatches[$i]);
    preg_match($patternArray[$i], $input, $ucmatches[]); // no need to force indexes
};
```

Comment: I want the for loop to create one multidimensional array for every of this 6  preq_match matches!

Comment: This will do it. The result will be something like: `[patternArray[0] => matches, patternArray[1] => matches]`

Comment: the problem is
    preq_match($pattern1, $input, $ucmatches)
leads to $ucmatches = array(1=>'abc'...40=>'xyz')

Comment: I wrote `preq_match($pattern1, $input, $ucmatches[])` It will introduce another dimension into array.

Comment: keo it worked perfectly didnt see i used preg_match instead of preg_macht_all!